# How do I locate an element in a NumPy array equal to a given value?

Tags: python, arrays

I work in the field of image processing, and I converted the image into a matrix. The values of this matrix are only two numbers: 0 and 255. I want to know where the value 0 is in which column and in which row it is repeated within this matrix. Please help
I wrote these

```
array = np.array(binary_img)
print("array",array)

for i in array:
    
    a = np.where(i==0)
    print(a)
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

The `==` operator on an array returns a boolean array of True/False values for each element.  The `argwhere` function returns the coordinates of the nonzero points in its parameter:

```
array = np.array(binary_img)
for pt in np.argwhere(array == 0):
    print( pt )
```